# How can I set a path to an executable in /usr/bin?

Tags: linux

I have a directory with different executables that I would like to be able to call from `/usr/bin`, how can I do it? Here I show an example image with `zipalign`, where the linked route is clearly shown

```
kali@kali:/usr/bin$ ls -l | grep "zipalign"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          46 May 10 04:32 zipalign -> **../lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian/zipalign**
kali@kali:/usr/bin$
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not Linux config issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Also, please do not post images of text. Paste the text directly into the question.

Comment: What does "call from /usr/bin" mean? Do you mean you want to create a symlink similar to what is shown? To do that the command would be like: `sudo ln -s /some/path/my_program /usr/bin/my_program`

Comment: An apology for my lack of stackoverflow documentation, indeed your answer has helped me, thank you very much, fully add the answer to give you the score

Comment: You'll better put local executables in `/usr/local/bin/` which you would add to your `$PATH`. Leave `/usr/bin/` *entirely managed* by your Linux distribution (e.g. [Debian](http://debian.org/)...). Read [hier(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) and [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)

Comment: @kaylum With your reputation you have the ability to move the poster question to the correct *StackExchange*.

Answer (score 2):

Executables are found in `PATH`. You have to add `/absolute/path/to/executables` to your `PATH`, like below (`vi $HOME/.bashrc`, later on `source $HOME/.bashrc` ):

```
export PATH="/path/to/my/executable/directory:$PATH"
```

**In your case**

```
export PATH="/absolute/path/to/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian:$PATH"
```

If you have root access and want for all users add in `/etc/profile`

Comment: I tried, but I want to make it permanent for all users and it did not allow me to do it even by modifying the `.bashrc` file or the `profile`

Comment: did you `source  $HOME/.bashrc` ? if for all users set in `/etc/profile` you need previlege to edit profile file

Comment: Yes, I did, but when I tried to run them from my `root` user it didn't allow it, and from my `kali `user it did.

Comment: @AdrMXR do  `sudo su`, then password, and then `vi /etc/profile`, save file, login to other user and test it, type `env | grep PATH` from other user terminal to verify path